# How to get class instanced using variable inside of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a class instance. I can't assign the class to a variable when I load it and then use it because I need to access the class based on what the user enters.

i.e: user goes to link website.com/classes/y, I need to access the instance with the name y.
I already handle the link and can get "y" or whatever the user entered by itself.

I have the class code as follows:

```
class LoadModel:

    existing_models = []


    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.name = model_path.parent.name
        self.__class__.existing_models.append(self.name)
```

For now, I can verify if the class exists using the existing_models list, but how will I be able to access it using the self.name?

I want to access it using LoadModel.name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep a dictionary of model names to instances. You could do that with something like:

```
class LoadModel:

    modelsByName = {}

    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.name = model_path.parent.name
        self.modelsByName[self.name] = self
```

Furthermore if you wanted to access an instance named `name` as `LoadModel.name` you could could add

```
setattr(self.__class__, self.name, self)
```

to `__init__`. Or if you were looking up by string (which it sounds like you might be) then you would just do `LoadModel.modelsbyName[name]`.

Note also that you don't need to use `self.__class__` when accessing members of the class that you have not *assigned* within the instance, and since you're only accessing the dictionary *object* defined in the class, you can use the reference inherited by the instance (`self.modelsByName`) instead of accessing the class explicitly (`self.__class__.modelsByName`).